# CSS changes after SharePoint 2010 to 2013 upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, css, upgrade

We have SP2010 project with CSS applied to SharePoint page CSS classes. Now in SP2013 we notice that few CSS classes like 'quick-launch' no longer exist. That means we will have to change the CSS accordingly. When the custom CSS code that looked cool in SP2010 is used in SP2013, it does not look so good, obviously because some classes have either changed or no longer exist.

I would like to know which are the classes that I have to look out for? Any reference to blog/articles will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the class/id names have changed. Some slightly, some significantly and some are still the same. Off the top of head and from briefly flipping through my notes a few (related to quick-launch and navigation):

```
/*2010 quick launch or current navigation*/    
#ms-quickLaunch { your styles }

/*2013 quick launch or current navigation*/
#sideNavBox { your styles }

/*2010 top nav or global navigation*/
.s4-toplinks { your styles }

/*2013 top nav or global navigation*/
.ms-breadcrumb-top { your styles }
```

The only reliable way I know to find all the differences is to open developer tools and compare. A great resource though is [Heather Solomon's blog](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/). She doesn't currently have a CSS chart for 2013 as she does for 2010 but I found this [article](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-css-classes-that-suck-and-save-the-day/) particularly helpful when we migrated to 2013.

If I have some time later I will try to update my answer with some of the other classes/ids I know to watch out for. Hope this helps.

Comment: Surprising that Microsoft have not documented the changes for quick reference.. or have they?

Comment: None so far as I have seen. would be really helpful if they did. This is the only [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms438349(v=office.14).aspx) I've ever seen--keep in mind it's for 2010 and pretty abysmal as a reference. I don't believe there is one for 2013.

Comment: Do update your answer as you get the information, this would help someone. I too will try to update.